# Background link in WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I have a website [dlazbazamkova.cz](https://dlazbazamkova.cz/) that works on Wordpress and I recently bought a GeneratePress template.

I ran into one problem - I have an ad in the background (JPG), but I can't insert a link. The link should be active everywhere (on a purple-black background), except for the main content of the page.

Is it possible to insert a link in the background of a page using HTML and CSS?
Is there a general solution or is it necessary to program a custom function?

Thank you in advance for your reply.
Have a nice day.
Martin Steidl

Comment: Sorry @Martins. You can't add any html link in a background image. You should change your markup for do this.

Comment: Hello,

is it really not possible? Maybe I misspelled what I needed. I don't need to insert a link to a background image. But I need to insert a link in the background of the page.

On this page (https://stavimbydlim.cz/prumerna-spotreba-vody-na-osobu/) I have inserted a background image and a link to the background of the page, using this code:

Comment: <style>
#body-wrap {
background-image: url("https://stavimbydlim.cz/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Branding_01.jpg");
max-width: 100%; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed; /* pozadí neroluje */
background-position: center top;
}
</style>
<a id="bgLinkLeft" href="https://www.porfix.cz/soutez/" target="blank"></a>
<a id="bgLinkRight" href="https://www.porfix.cz/soutez/" target="blank"></a>

Thank you in advance for your reply. Have a nice day. Martin Steidl